# member server not showing in ibm liberty 20.0.0.x cluster

Tags: websphere, websphere-liberty

Executed the below steps:
1.server create myController
2.collective create myController --keystorePassword=demoPassword and updated server.xml of myController
3.add   to server.xml of mycontroller
4.server create myMember1
5.usr\servers\myController\resources\security install certs to machine
6.collective join myMember --host=host1 --port=9443 --user=admin --password=pass --keystorePassword=demoPassword,cmd result updated in myMemeber server.xml  with collectiveMember-1.0 and clusterMember-1.0 features and started myMember .

But myMember not showing in the cluster.Is there any step missing in the above points, if cluster member added to myController server, then cluster shows myController but never shows collection members.
Is there any step missing in the above points?

Comment: Is the member showing up in the collective, just not the cluster (aka, did the member successfully join the collective)?  If it's not part of the collective, make sure the member machine can communicate with the controller machine (try testConnection: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSD28V_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.core.doc/ae/tagt_wlp_configure_collective.html)


I'm guessing that between steps 3 and 4, the controller was started?

Comment: M. Broz  ->  I'm guessing that between steps 3 and 4, the controller was started?  yes

Comment: executed , collective testConnection wasvm,${wlp.user.dir},controller1  --host=wasvm --port=9443 --user=admin --password=pass --autoAcceptCertificates , gets the below 
Error: CWWKX7243E: The collective controller did not find authentication information for host: wasvm,${wlp.user.dir},controller1. The specified host is not registered with the collective controller or the authentication information was not set. The received error is: CWWKX0261E: The host authentication information for the host csvm is not available.

Comment: So that means the member's machine can't communicate with the controller's machine (because host auth info wasn't provided).  You'll need the member's host machine to be registered with the controller (with proper creds), which can be done via collective register/updateHost commands.  See https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSD28V_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.core.doc/ae/tagt_wlp_registerhost.html and https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSD28V_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.core.doc/ae/rwlp_ui_trouble.html#rwlp_ui_trouble__noauth

Comment: usrDirPath = ${wlp.user.dir} is correct parameter ? both member and controller are in same vm. Does the members and controller should be configured with same httpPort and httpsPort or different? And members and controller  cannot be in same host when they are same vm?                                                                                             
tried :collective registerHost --host=csvm --port=9443 --user=admin --password=admin shows below log Aborting registerHost.
Error: Host wasvm is already registered.

Comment: You can have the member and controller on the same host, no issues there.  The member and controller must use different http/https ports, otherwise there would be a port conflict (whichever server would be second to start would say it couldn't obtain the port).  The error makes sense since the host was already registered because they the member and controller are on the same host.  Instead you need to run the collective updateHost command to update csvm host with either ssh or rpc information

Comment: broz, it is mentioned while setting ur RXA in windows, that to Ensure that your collective controller is running with an IBM JDK.https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSD28V_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.core.doc/ae/twlp_set_rxa.html . is it not possible to setup RXA with openjdk or oracle jdk?

Comment: according to https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSD28V_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.core.doc/ae/tagt_wlp_configure_collective.html, collectiveController-1.0 feature and its capabilities are available only in WebSphere® Application Server Network Deployment Liberty and WebSphere Application Server for z/OS® Liberty , which ibm liberty version and type of server has to be considered for windows ?

Comment: Regarding the JDK, I believe that's correct, an IBM JDK is necessary for RXA on windows to work.  You could try OpenJDK with J9 to see if that works, but given the documentation, I would not expect support.  If you need to run on a non-IBM JDK for a windows collective then I'd recommend using SSH instead (install a third-party SSH service on your windows machine, like Cygwin).

Comment: Regarding what Liberty versions are applicable to Windows, they all are, except z/OS since that's specifically meant for running on z/OS (in other words, Core, Base, ND).  However, collectives are only available in ND (Network Deployment) and z/OS, so if you want to use collectives on Windows, you need to use ND edition.